# Where can i find the updated source code of design support library?

Tags: android

I searched a lot on web and `SDK` directory for the source code of design support library. I found some related resources but it seems they are not updated. I found the source of design support library at the links given below, but it is different from library source code and classes i am using in my project.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/

**Work-space snap.**

[image]

But there are less classes on web than project. As it is a compressed jar, that's why can't browse its code.
Thanks in advance and any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the source code on your hard drive, at least if you have the Android Repository installed.

Go to `$ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/$VERSION`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever your Android SDK is installed and `$VERSION` is some version of the library. In there, you will find a `design-$VERSION-sources.jar` file for the same `$VERSION`, which contains your source code.

Comment: But it contains class files only, which are encrypted.I need java files.

Comment: @sourabhbans: No, the `design-$VERSION-sources.jar` file contains source code. That is why it has `sources` in the filename.

Comment: thanks ... got it.. but i found only for 23.1.0 and i have 22.2.0, 22.2.1 and more. and there is no source files in others... can i ask why?

Comment: @sourabhbans: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Ooohkey... thnks again.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the design support library has not been updated in the public repositories in a while (9 weeks ago as of October 21st, 2015).

This means that the source is not currently publicly available on the web, and the best you can if you want to view it on the web is patiently wait.

Answer (score -1):

You can clone the repo at the following address :
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/

Comment: plz,, read the question before copy and paste the answer... thanks